# Calling sync ready made async ajax javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I want to call this function on button click after login and wait for result, to get token value. This function cannot be changed, it is async and supplied from other currently unavailable team.

I already tried something like this, but with no success. I get web service results, but I can't write appropriate sync call to wait to return token.

```
function getToken() {

    param1 = "123456";

    ajax_oauth(param1, function (success, response) {
        success: return response.token;    
    }); 

}

function ajax_oauth(param1, callback) {
    APP.debug("oauth login with param1 " + param1);
    try {
        APP.blockUI();
        var DeviceID = APP.readRegistry(APP_CONFIG.REGISTRY.DeviceID);
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        $.ajax(
            auth_token_url,
            {
                method: "GET",
                accept: 'application/json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    'param1': param1,
                    'deviceId': DeviceID
                }),
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: false
                },
                statusCode: {
                    201: function (response) {
                        APP_STATE.hasOauth = true;
                        APP.debug('got response 200 from oauth');
                        auth.login(response.token); //TODO read expiration from token
                        try {
                            var decoded = jwt_decode(response.token);
                            APP_STATE.uid = decoded.uid;
                        } catch (err) {
                            APP.error("unable to decode token " + JSON.stringify(err));
                        }
                    },
                    401: function () {

                    },
                    500: function () {

                    },
                    503: function () {

                    }
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    APP.unblockUI();
                    APP_STATE.restAvailable = true;
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    APP.unblockUI();
                    APP_STATE.restAvailable = false;
                    APP.restError(auth_token_url, jqXHR, errorThrown, textStatus);
                    APP.callback(callback, false);
                }
            }
        );
    } catch (err) {
        APP.error("unable to do oauth login, " + err);
    }
};
```

After user clicks on login button, I want to call function `ajax_oauth` and to return token if params ok. If not, to return login error. Login can't be async, as far as I can see.

Comment: Logically, every login is sync activity. You can't do anything until you log in to your sistem. Right? So windows cannot let you play tetris while checking for your credentials in background. That's what I mean with can't be async. But some clever developer write it async and I'm in trouble. :-)

Comment: that's not possible.

Comment: King Stone, just after login I use some params for getting token for session...What is the possible solution Kevin B? Is async design of function ajax_oauth completely wrong?

Comment: @MickeyJason getToken simply cannot return the value, it must return a promise or accept a callback.

Comment: How can it accept callback?

Comment: Anytime you access the Server it should be Asynchronously. In this case your Client clicks a button which calls your AJAX function. You do something with the response on `success`.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason you can't tap into the original ajax response, you could intercept the request using [`$.ajaxPrefilter`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/).

From your code it looks like `auth_token_url` has a global reference. You could use this to intercept the call by matching the outgoing request on the resource URL.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter('json', function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  if (options.url === auth_token_url) {
    jqXHR.done(function(response) {
      try {
        var decoded = jwt_decode(response.token);
        console.log(decoded);
      } catch (err) {
        APP.error("unable to decode token " + JSON.stringify(err));
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Note that this needs to be declared well before the request is made preferably after jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Thank you guys. This workaround did the job. Entire code will be rewritten soon, so intercept is accepted.